How do I remove multiple underscores from a concatenated formula that is pulling from a drop down?
I want to concatenate a series of columns with each value separated by an underscore in a table
The problem is that the columns to be concatenated are leveraging data validation lists, and not all columns will be used each time the table is updated. How can I concatenate the columns but ensure there are not multiple underscores in a row?
Current output
I've tried using the below formula, but this creates a series of multiple underscores.
=B3&"_"&C3&"_"&D3&"_"&E3&"_"&F3&"_"&G3&"_"

Then I tried to use another column to at least remove the trailing underscores which works, but only if I know that there will always be specific number of underscores to be removed from the end of the string.
=IF(RIGHT(H5,1)="_",LEFT(H5,LEN(H5)-1),H5)
2nd formula
How can I combine inputs within columns B-H, separated by a underscore, but remove the extra underscores if a drop down is not used?
